Stackoverflow em Português é muito desmotivador, comunidade muito exigente para iniciantes, o que fazer?
Eu sou professor da área de TI, brasileiro, atuo esporadicamente no stackoverflow em inglês. Como professor com frequência eu estimulo meus estudantes a usarem Q&As como o stackoverflow como forma de iniciar o engajamento deles em comunidades de desenvolvimento. Acredito que quanto mais engajamento e crescimento da comunidade, melhor ela será.
Desmotivação por negativação
No entanto, desde que fiz minhas primeiras postagens aqui no stackoverflow em português, eu confesso que me distanciei bastante desta comunidade e fiquei muito decepcionado, pois mesmo querendo ajudar e criando respostas o mais construtivas possíveis no meu limitado ponto de vista, ainda assim, ou a resposta não tinha engajamento (o que não vejo como um problema imediato já que a comunidade está se consolidando) ou então a resposta era negativada, sem qualquer razão de ser e sem um comentário sequer explicando o motivo ou solicitando que a resposta fosse melhorada.
Apesar de isso acontecer também em algumas situações no stackoverflow em inglês, isso é relativamente raro. O mais comum é que aconteça o contrário: a comunidade valoriza as respostas e, caso julguem que ela precise ser melhorada, costumam comentar ao negativar ou sequer negativam.
Desmotivação por perguntas apagadas/fechadas
Outro problema que ocorre com frequência é a exclusão ou fechamento de perguntas. Eu considero apagar e até fechar uma pergunta por ser de baixa qualidade algo extremamente desmotivador, sobretudo para iniciantes que não usam o stackoverflow em inglês, justamente porque não se sentem seguros para tal, e ao virem ao stackoverflow em português procurando ser acolhido, encontram uma comunidade que o exclui. O fazem apenas porque ele não soube se expressar, usar os termos corretos, anexar exemplos e/ou imagens (que pode ser que a pessoa nem saiba como fazer ou mesmo tem dificuldades sequer de criar um exemplo). Quem nunca em uma aula não deixou de perguntar, não porque não tinha dúvidas, mas porque ficou tão perdido que sequer sabia o que e como perguntar?
Comentário tóxicos
Comentários ácidos também são extremamente comuns, em vez de apontar como a pergunta poderia melhorar de forma cortês, é muito comum ver comentários desnecessariamente agressivos, como se a pessoa que perguntou o tivesse insultado e criado um trabalho desnecessário.
Reflexão
Eu acredito que um Q&A como o stackoverflow, sobretudo em português, deveria ser uma comunidade mais aberta, inclusiva e acolhedora, justamente porque quem o procura é porque não se sente seguro sequer para perguntar ou procurar recursos em inglês e, sinceramente, existe um enorme gap de materiais atualizados em português dedicados a iniciantes em praticamente todas as áreas da computação. Acredito que quem se envolve em um Q&A das duas uma:

ou está buscando conhecimento;
ou quer compartilhar conhecimento e/ou discutir questões visando um engrandecimento próprio e da comunidade.

Então, nesse sentido, qual a razão de haver comentários tóxicos, fechar e excluir perguntas, ou de sequer haver um mecanismo de negativar perguntas e respostas?
Acredito que, muito pelo contrário, o único mecanismo que deveria existir de censura é justamente de denunciar usuários, respostas e comentários tóxicos que não agregam em nada para a comunidade, esses sim é que deveriam ser excluídos da comunidade e não o iniciante que está dando seus primeiros passos no mundo da TI e não sabe como anexar uma imagem ou como criar blocos de código para estruturar melhor sua pergunta.
Caso contrário apenas passaremos como comunidade a mensagem de que somos uma comunidade exclusiva para especialistas pedantes que não têm tempo a perder com principiantes.

Tem algum exemplo de comentário tóxico? Porque se tiver existe as flags ao lado de qualquer comentário que você pode denunciar a qualquer momento. Não confunda instruções de melhorias ou explicações sobre o motivo do fechamento da pergunta com ser tóxico, são coisas diferentes. Observe também que os votos são sistema de avaliação e não de censura, para ser censura algo teria que ser removido sem devidas explicações, o que não ocorre.

Links úteis e que explicam todas as suas dúvidas: 1) finalidade do site, 2) o que são votos no site 3) Por que e como algumas perguntas são excluídas? 4) Dicas sobre o funcionamento do fechamento e reabertura de perguntas

É importante ter em mente que isso tudo dito na sua dúvida, aqui no META, já foi debatido e explicado diversas vezes em outras publicações no META, um dos muitos exemplos que ajudará a entender é o Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?.

A conversa ficou excessivamente longa e foi movida para o chat; - queiram consultar os pontos debatidos e/ou participar usando o link fornecido
